# How does function named connect() prevent MPI C program from running?

Tags: c, function, runtime-error, mpi, program-entry-point

I was writing a project using MPI for a parallel programming course, and decided to name one of my functions `connect()`. But whenever I tried to `mpirun` the program (using recent versions of Open MPI on Linux and OS X), I would receive output from the `connect()` function, even if I had not called `connect()` from `main()`; also, some of the output from `main()` would not appear.

This is a simplified program with the issue:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void connect(); //function name breaks mpi

int main(void) {

    int comm_sz, my_rank;
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    printf("my_rank is %d\n", my_rank);
    fflush(stdout);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void connect() {

    printf("\nNot main! \n");
    return;
}
```

and the output:

```
[me@host ~]$ mpicc bad.c -Wall
[me@host ~]$ mpirun -n 1 a.out 

Not main! 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
orterun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 17245 on node host exited on signal 13 (Broken pipe).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I was about to ask on Stack Overflow what was wrong in the first place, until I discovered that renaming the function fixes it. So what I'm curious about now is why naming the function `connect()` prevents the program from running correctly. Could it also be an issue with `mpirun`/Open RTE?

Possible leads:

- There's a `connect()` function in `<sys/socket.h>`, but I haven't yet found it mentioned in the MPI header files.
- There's also a `Connect()` function (with an uppercase C) in `"ompi/mpi/cxx/intracomm.h"` which is indirectly included by `<mpi.h>`, but I thought case mattered in C/C++, and it looks like a method of a C++ class.
- If I try executing the program like a normal one, it works when run on OS X, but not on Linux:



```
mac:~ me$ ./a.out 
my_rank is 0
```

vs

```
[me@linux ~]$ ./a.out 

Not main!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would guess that one of the MPI functions you call is in turn calling the `connect()` system call. But since ELF executables have a flat namespace for symbols, your `connect()` is being called instead.

The problem doesn't happen on Mac OS because Mach-O libraries have a two-level namespace, so symbols in different libraries don't conflict with each other.

If you make your function static, that would probably avoid the problem as well.

Comment: Hooray for namespaces!

Comment: I had assumed the `main()` function wasn't getting called, but after examining this suggestion it appears to always be called; I will add more `printf()` before and between the MPI functions to identify at least the first problematic one. Also, the static suggestion works. Is there a way to further investigate if the `connect()` system call is indeed called, or otherwise identify the namespace conflict?

Comment: As one of the authors of Open MPI, I'll confirm that the answer provided by +elbows is correct: Open MPI makes use of the connect(2) system call.  When you have a public function named connect(2) (probably as part of MPI_Init), the linker will end up invoking *your* connect() function rather than connect(2).  Bad Things happen from there.